# Automatically check Yes/No boxes on table

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible to create a button that presses the check box for every record in a table?

Comment: You can apologize for it making little sense, or you can try to explain it so that it does (perhaps talk to a colleague/rubber duck. write it on paper, etc). Programs don't "know" things, they're programmed to do a certain thing in a certain condition, and I don't understand what you intend to do.

Comment: Sounds great. Now please read [ask], see [help/on-topic], and glance at [mcve].

Comment: Well, the question sure got a lot more minimal. But do you really want to press a check box a whole lot of times, or do you just want to execute an update query on the underlying table?

Comment: The answer is yes. The button will run code - an update query - as Erik von Asmuth described.

Answer (score 0):

Something like . . . all invoices with a balance due that are 30 days late have the LateStatus field updated to True.

```
UPDATE tblInvoices
SET [LateStatus] = True
WHERE (([Balance] > 0) AND ([InvoiceDate] < Date()-30)
```